# Suppress warnings when using command line Swift compiler

Tags: swift

The Swift command line compiler provides warnings and notes mixed in with errors.  Is there any way to suppress the warnings and notes?

I've reviewed the options for "swift build" by using "swift build --help" and there was nothing helpful there that I could see.

Comment: Something to keep in mind - warnings should be fixed, not ignored. Most warnings indicate real problems in your code. Fixing the underlying cause of the warning is a much better plan.

Answer (score 4):

The option is simply called `-suppress-warnings`, f.e.

```
swiftc -suppress-warnings Test.swift
```

But you shouldn't do that, there is a reason for every warning. Better solve the issues instead of just hiding them.

Comment: The reason to (temporarily) suppress warnings is to prioritize work on solving errors.  It's not that I won't solve the issues with the warnings - I will - but I want to get my code to compile first.  I prefer my answer because it is less permanent, but thanks for letting me know about that feature!

Comment: To pass to `swift build` use `swift build -Xswiftc -suppress-warnings`.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that I can just grep out the lines to get the errors:

```
swift build | grep error
```